# JavaScript Second Largest Element in array Error in code

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wrote this code to get second max...it worked in cases like nums=[1,2,3,2,4] and i got second max equal to 3.But if mu array is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] the output for second max is 8.
Please help.

```
function getSecondLargest(arr){
  let uniqueArr = [ ...new Set(arr) ];
  uniqueArr.sort();
  const z= uniqueArr.length;
  return arr[z-2];
}
```

Comment: make sure you are parsing the values as integers or floats and not strings because 10 is after 1 alphabetically

Comment: please add the code to the question. what does not work?

Comment: The issue here is that if you use the `sort()` method alone, `1 < 10 < 2`. If you run `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].sort()` you see that the result is `[1,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

Comment: *"The default sort order is ascending, built upon converting the elements into strings, then comparing their sequences of UTF-16 code units values."*  - [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Got the answer ,Thanks everybody for helping me out.I didn't knew how sort() works ....

Answer (score 5):

try this

```js
let intArray =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
console.log(intArray.sort((a, b) => b - a)[1]);
```

Comment: You can also use the es6 syntax with arrow-functions: `intArray.sort((a, b) => b - a)[1]`

Comment: @johannchopin Thanks. I have update my code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function getSecondLargest(nums){
    let sort = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    return sort[sort.length - 2]
}

console.log(getSecondLargest(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is sorting the elements alphabetically. Try passing the function in the sort:

```js
let arr1 = [1,2,3,2,4];
let arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

console.log( getSecondLargest(arr1) );
console.log( getSecondLargest(arr2) );

function getSecondLargest(arr){
  let uniqueArr = [ ...new Set(arr) ];
  uniqueArr.sort((a,b)=> a-b);
  const z= uniqueArr.length;
  return arr[z-2];
}
```

I recommend you take care of edge cases such as arrays of length 0 or 1...

Answer (score 0):

It is returning 8 because `sort()` method in javascript by default sorts the array in alphabetical order, so applying `sort()` method to your will return something like this:-

```
[1,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

So, in order to sort them numerically, you've to add this new method which is further simplified by using arrows functions in ES6. Following will be your updated code:-

```js
function getSecondLargest(arr){
  let uniqueArr = [ ...new Set(arr) ];
  uniqueArray.sort((a,b) => a-b);
  const z= uniqueArr.length;
  return arr[z-2];
}
```